# How to know if the browser REALLY finished browsing

Tags: vb.net, events, event-handling, browser, geckofx

I'm usually get to know if the browser has finished loading with DocumentCompleted event.

But lately, When I'm trying site like http://youtube.com, the documentcompleted event is firing up more than once.
I placed console.writeline to check what's happened

```
Private Sub mybrowser_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Gecko.GeckoNavigatingEventArgs) Handles mybrowser.Navigating
    Console.WriteLine("navigating " + e.Uri.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub

Private Sub mybrowser_Navigated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Gecko.GeckoNavigatedEventArgs) Handles mybrowser.Navigated
    Console.WriteLine("navigated " + e.Uri.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub

Private Sub mybrowser_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles mybrowser.DocumentCompleted
    Console.WriteLine("document " + mybrowser.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri)
End Sub
```

The result is (test with http://youtube.com)

```
navigating http://youtube.com/
navigated http://www.youtube.com/
document http://www.youtube.com/
navigating http://www.google.com/pagead/drt/ui
navigated wyciwyg://0/http://www.youtube.com/
navigating wyciwyg://0/http://www.youtube.com/
document http://www.youtube.com/
navigating about:blank
document http://www.youtube.com/
document http://www.youtube.com/
```

As you can see, the site is redirecting and firing up navigating event several time, including cache, google pagead site and about:blank(???). Each navigating event will be ended by documentcompleted event.

So, what event should I listened if I just want to know when the browser REALLY completed browsing the site no matter how many redirect?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about older versions, but in version 12.0 of GeckoFx, there are two useful properties:

- IsBusy
- IsAjaxBusy

You can determine if the browser is done loading the document and all the stuff by checking for this two properties:

```
if (geckofx.IsBusy || geckofx.IsAjaxBusy)
{
    // still busy, not finished yet
}
else
{
    // finished
}
```

The example is C#, sorry. But you can probably convert it to VB.NET better than I can.

Answer (score 1):

Add this event handler and routine in VB.net

```
Sub PageLoaded_Event(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles GeckoWebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
    PageLoaded = True
End Sub

Sub WaitForNav()
    While PageLoaded = False
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    PageLoaded = False
End Sub
```

Then after every geckowebbrowser.navigate(www...) call WaitForNav.

Hope this helps others